# Extending Helpers in Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm working on a Spree application, and I had to override a view without using Deface. So I created an `html.erb` file in the same path of its Spree original counterpart, and with the same name. It works.
Now I'd like to define a helper to be used in such a view, so I tried to create a decorator file for the helper used in the original view, and to extend the helper module using `module_eval`.
It's not working...

Comment: Try using `class_eval`.

Comment: `OrdersHelper` in Spree is a module, not a class.

Comment: AFAIK all helpers are, but I'm using `class_eval` for that and it works.

Comment: According to that: http://ruby-metaprogramming.rubylearning.com/html/ruby_metaprogramming_3.html they're the same method, each may be used either with a module or a class, so maybe show your code and error.